# Linq query performance improvements

Tags: c#, performance, linq

As I am getting my Linq query to a functional point, I start looking at the query and think about all the "ANY" and wonder if those should be a different method and then I have data conversions going on.

Does anything jump out as being a performance issue? What is recommended to make this more performant? (Yes, I need all the `&&`.)

```
etchVector =
    from vio in list
    where excelViolations.Any(excelVio => vio.VioID.Formatted.Equals(excelVio.VioID.ToString()))
    && excelViolations.Any(excelVio => vio.RuleType.Formatted.Equals(excelVio.RuleType))
    && excelViolations.Any(excelVio => vio.VioType.Formatted.Equals(excelVio.VioType)) 
    && excelViolations.Any(excelVio => vio.EtchVects.Any(x => x.XCoordinate.Equals(excelVio.XCoordinate)))
    && excelViolations.Any(excelVio => vio.EtchVects.Any(y => y.YCoordinate.Equals(excelVio.YCoordinate)))
    select new EtchVectorShapes
    {
        VioID = Convert.ToInt32(vio.EtchVects.Select(x => x.VioID)),
        ObjectType = vio.EtchVects.Select(x => x.ObjectType).ToString(),
        XCoordinate = Convert.ToDouble(vio.EtchVects.Select(x => x.XCoordinate)),
        YCoordinate = Convert.ToDouble(vio.EtchVects.Select(x => x.YCoordinate)),
        Layer = vio.EtchVects.Select(x => x.Layer).ToString()      
    };
```

Comment: Do you need to perform the `ToList()` call? This will (of course) freeze the enumerable contents at creation time, so maybe this is hat you require; but maybe not.

Comment: I honestly don't see anything to improve regarding the performance of the LINQ portion of the query.

Comment: Though it would be nice to refactor some of those operations into separate methods, IMHO.

Comment: And the universal answer for all performance questions: what did the profiler say was slow?

Comment: I haven't ran it through any profiler, I certainly need to.  Just looking to see if there is a code smell or something obvious that someone sees that is a "yikes"  ( like a cursor in sql server comes to mind).  thx

Comment: 1) Does this code even work? `Convert.ToDouble(vio.EtchVects.Select(x => x.YCoordinate))` looks weird. 2) Which variant of LINQ is this? Linq-to-objects? 3) How many entries does `excelViolations` have?

Comment: Your &&Any logic looks weird. Are you sure you want it like that? In your code each property of `vio` needs a matching entry in `excelViolation`, but the matches can be in different entries. For example if for one of the `excelViolation` entries everything except the xCoordinate match, and another entry has almost everything wrong but xCoordinate matches those together allow `vio` to pass.

Comment: Yikes, you are right.  Those Convert.ToDoubles and even the ToString() do not work.  What can I do to get the correct types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is without optimizations, but the errors that you describe seem to be in how you are getting the data.

Based on your lists within list and the error message you are getting , try something like this:

```
etchVector = list.Where(vio => excelViolations.Any(currVio => vio.VioID.Formatted.Equals(currVio.VioID.ToString())
                        && vio.RuleType.Formatted.Equals(currVio.RuleType)
                        && vio.VioType.Formatted.Equals(currVio.VioType)
                        && vio.Bows.Any(bw => bw.XCoordinate.Equals(currVio.XCoordinate))
                        && vio.Bows.Any(bw1 => bw1.YCoordinate.Equals(currVio.YCoordinate)))).SelectMany(vi => vi.EtchVects).ToList();
```

Comment: that works, interesting.  that fixed my data problem, now onto the optimization.  thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can definitely optimize this query. If `list` has M items and `excelViolations` has N items, the query will iterate `excelViolations` M*5N times.

It is possible to reduce this to M*N iterations by consuming `excelViolations` only once per item in `list`. You can do this with a subquery on `excelViolations` that checks all five conditions for each `excelVio`, then ORs each of the five conditions across all `excelVio` instances.

If that is not clear, hopefully this walkthrough is:

```
from vio in list

// Perform all five checks for each excelVio

let checks = excelViolations
    .Select(excelVio => new
    {
        HasVioID = vio.VioID.Formatted.Equals(excelVio.VioID.ToString()),
        HasRuleType = vio.RuleType.Formatted.Equals(excelVio.RuleType),
        HasVioType = vio.VioType.Formatted.Equals(excelVio.VioType),
        HasXCoordinate = vio.EtchVects.Any(x => x.XCoordinate.Equals(excelVio.XCoordinate)),
        HasYCoordinate = vio.EtchVects.Any(y => y.YCoordinate.Equals(excelVio.YCoordinate))
    })

// From left to right, OR each of the five results (equivalent to .Any)

    .Aggregate((left, right) => new
    {
        HasVioID = (left.HasVioID || right.HasVioID),
        HasRuleType = (left.HasRuleType || right.HasRuleType),
        HasVioType = (left.HasVioType || right.HasVioType),
        HasXCoordinate = (left.HasXCoordinate || right.HasXCoordinate),
        HasYCoordinate = (left.HasYCoordinate || right.HasYCoordinate)
    })

// Filter to only those that pass every check

where checks.HasVioID
    && checks.HasRuleType
    && checks.HasVioType
    && checks.HasXCoordinate
    && checks.HasYCoordinate

// Same projection

select new EtchVectorShapes
{
    VioID = Convert.ToInt32(vio.EtchVects.Select(x => x.VioID)),
    ObjectType = vio.EtchVects.Select(x => x.ObjectType).ToString(),
    XCoordinate = Convert.ToDouble(vio.EtchVects.Select(x => x.XCoordinate)),
    YCoordinate = Convert.ToDouble(vio.EtchVects.Select(x => x.YCoordinate)),
    Layer = vio.EtchVects.Select(x => x.Layer).ToString()
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The underlying problem is that vio.EtchVects is `IEnumerable<T>`, and LINQ `IEnumerable<T>.Select` functions still return `IEnumerable<T>`.  Your `Convert.ToX` functions are expecting scalar values.

For simplicity, I will build from @Bryan Watts' answer, starting only with the select statement.

If you want only the EtchVectors as a flat list, you can do the following:

```
from vect in vio.EtchVects
select new EtchVectorShapes
{
    VioID = Convert.ToInt32(vect.VioID),
    ObjectType = vect.ObjectType.ToString(),
    XCoordinate = Convert.ToDouble(vect.XCoordinate),
    YCoordinate = Convert.ToDouble(vect.YCoordinate),
    Layer = vect.Layer.ToString()
};
```

If you want them to retain the same organizational hierarchy they started with, you can do something similar to the following:

```
select new EtchVectorShapes
{
    Shapes = from vect in vio.EtchVects
             select new EtchVectorShape
             {
                 VioID = Convert.ToInt32(vect.VioID),
                 ObjectType = vect.ObjectType.ToString(),
                 XCoordinate = Convert.ToDouble(vect.XCoordinate),
                 YCoordinate = Convert.ToDouble(vect.YCoordinate),
                 Layer = vect.Layer.ToString()
             }
};
```

If you only want one of the vectors from each vio, you could use one of the scalar LINQ functions (e.g., First or Last) or one of the aggregate functions (e.g., Max or Sum):

```
let vect = vio.EtchVects.First ()
select new EtchVectorShapes
{
    VioID = Convert.ToInt32(vect.VioID),
    ObjectType = vect.ObjectType.ToString(),
    XCoordinate = Convert.ToDouble(vect.XCoordinate),
    YCoordinate = Convert.ToDouble(vect.YCoordinate),
    Layer = vect.Layer.ToString()
};
```

Comment: I still get errors as mentioned above with all the conversions like Convert.ToInt32 etc..   VioID = Convert.ToInt32(vect.VioID),
    ObjectType = vect.ObjectType.ToString(),
    XCoordinate = Convert.ToDouble(vect.XCoordinate),
    YCoordinate = Convert.ToDouble(vect.YCoordinate),
    Layer = vect.Layer.ToString()